# Basic Python program, keeps telling me my elements in list are strings not integers?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to create this function to multiply 2 positive integers from the user. When I run the code it basically says that the list elements are strings not ints, even though I specify in the input loop that I want the strings converted to ints. Not really sure what's going on? (n.b. I do know this is all highly unnecessary lol but I am a beginner and just trying to learn with basic challenges. Thank you)

```
def multiply(a, b):
    c = a * b
    return c

input_list = []
for items in range(1, 3):
    input1 = (input('Enter 2 positive, whole numbers you would like to multiply '))
    int(input1)
    input_list = input_list + [input1]  

result = multiply(input_list[0], input_list[1])
print(result)
```

Comment: you have to cast your string to integer like this : int(a) or int(b)

Comment: An easy fix will be to assign your cast integer to a new variable then append that variable instead. The cast doesn't work in place so just calling the method wouldn't change the variable. However, there are a couple more "bugs" in your code besides this one.

Comment: Your program would be fine in Python2 (since apparently, `int()` performed the conversion in-place in the old days). In Python3, it returns a new integer instead - therefore, you have to assign its return value to a variable (as mentioned in the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You convert input1 to an integer but you don't save the result:

```
int(input1)
```

You must do:

```
input1 = int(input1)
```

Comment: Thank you. And just so everyone knows, I only have 9 rep so my up votes don't show publicly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiply(a, b):
    c = a * b
    return c

input_list = []
for items in range(1, 3):
    input1 = (input('Enter 2 positive, whole numbers you would like to multiply '))
    input_list.append(int(input1))


result = multiply(input_list[0], input_list[1])
print(result)
```

Try this.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you have any other issues. You can upvote or accept the answer if you feel helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    c = a * b
    return c


numbers = []
for items in range(2):
    string = input('Enter a number you would like to multiply: ')
    number = int(string)
    numbers.append(number)


result = multiply(numbers[0], numbers[1])
print(result)
```